# configure SNMP Trap monitoring in Nagios

Tags: snmp, snmp-trap

I am struggling a lot to understand and setup SNMP Trap monitoring using Nagios monitoring tool.
I followed many tutorials and articles over internet but unable to understand below 2 points:

1) Understanding about SNMP Trap monitoring, why we do SNMP trap monitoring ?
2) How do we implement SNMP Trap monitoring using Nagios monitoring tool ?

Any help on above 2 points would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hi, this doesn't look like a programming question to me. It looks like a question about how to use an enterprise network management application (Nagios). Please post such questions on ServerFault.com instead.

Answer (score -1):

Most network devices keep a database called Management Information Base (MIB). This is used to track information related to hardware including health. To get this information you have to provide an OID or the Object Identifier which is different for different vendors.

Through SNMP you can query any of the OIDs from a device. Let's say you have a Cisco Router and you want to make sure it does not over heat. So you check the OID for temperature every 5-10 minutes and then on Nagios you configure certain limits, for example if the temperature ever increases above 45c then Nagios should send you an alert etc. Similarly you can monitor other OIDs.

So the question is how do you use SNMP with Nagios?
Nagios has a script called check_snmp that does this for you.

```
check_snmp -H <ip_address> -o <OID> [-w warn_range] [-c crit_range]
[-C community] [-s string] [-r regex] [-R regexi] [-t timeout] [-e  retries]
[-l label] [-u units] [-p port-number] [-d delimiter] [-D output-delimiter]
[-m miblist] [-P snmp version] [-L seclevel] [-U secname] [-a authproto]
[-A authpasswd] [-x privproto] [-X privpasswd]
```

As you can see you can provide the IP address, OID, your warning and critical thresholds and authentication information etc. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Junaid,

first of all thanks for your response and information you provided is very useful & informative but i am already aware of how to setup SNMP monitoring under nagios, my question was how do we setup "SNMP Trap" monitoring in Nagios and why do we need to setup "SNMP Trap" monitoring though we have SNMP monitoring concept available. below i am mentioning my questions more clearly:


1) how do we setup "SNMP Trap" monitoring in Nagios ?
2) why do we need to setup "SNMP Trap" monitoring though we have SNMP monitoring concept available ?

Thanks,
Jonus Joseph

Comment: Sorry it's been a while and i have not replied to this post. I am sure by now you would have figured it out but the way I understand it, SNMP Trap is the opposite of SNMP monitoring, in the sense that your configure an appliance let's say a router for SNMP trap so that if a particular event occurs it notifies a monitoring system.